# Differential equation problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The text of the task is the following :  For what values of $x_0$, $y_0$ does the differential equation $xy'=(x-y)^{1/2}$  have a unique solution  $y=y(x)$ such that $y(x_0)=y_0$? Have no idea how to solve that diffur. Even wolfram doesnt give an answer , maybe here is something that i do not see.

Comment: Try putting $x-y=z$. Anyway, you are probably supposed to apply a general theorem.

Comment: What is general theorem?

Comment: A general theorem about existence and uniqueness